# 500 issue from server when I upload image and resize

Tags: php, laravel, server, http-status-code-500

What is the best solution to overcome this problem?

I have a solution to fix it, but I want the best solution.

I have used ini_get ("upload_max_filesize") and the problem was solved.

Comment: You have to change the value in the php.ini on the server. That is the best solution, but you can do it just if you have access to the server

Comment: _“I have used ini_get ("upload_max_filesize") the problem has solved”_ - it surely hasn’t. Apart from that it is not possible to manipulate that setting at run-time, only _getting_ the current value would not change anything to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting your accepted max file size is the right thing to do.
As @giacomo-m said, you have to change it server side.

Also don't forget to also change `post_max_size` (file are send within POST request, if you accept 24Mo files but 16Mo POST data, it won't work)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I want another solution. because of all server, not the same configuration then every time it would change.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?
You will never be able to upload images bigger than the default (2Mo in php7.2) limit if you do not want to change it.